# Why use MakeCurrent() with NULL parameters?

Tags: multithreading, opengl

I already know that xxxMakeCurrent(...), -let me call it "MC-par"- must be used before any gl command. My question is about xxxMakeCurrent(null parameters), let me call it "MC-null"

I understand that is a good practice to call MC-null at window-close event, so as to release the context for (perhaps) another window.
Does the OS uses it automatically, for example, right before the window/surface is destroyed? If so, there's no problem with avoiding calling MC-null in app code.

Some people prefer to use all gl commands in a secondary thread, so they use MC-par inside that thread.
And other people use one or more threads with the same context. But instead of sharing this context, they prefer to call MC-null in, for example, main thread; then MC-par in some thread, do gl-stuff, and MC-null again in this thread. Perhaps glDrawxxx in the paint-event of the main thread.
You see, moving context from threat to thread continuously.

These usages are done to "save GUI from delaying/blocking". Or to do offscreen rendering.

I don't know if people reads the docs and is aware that glFlush is called by OS/driver before the context is released or detached. Some delay appears here.

Also, I don't know what happens when the GUI must be updated in the (likely) main thread but another thread is still issuing gl commands, because normally the GPU is not able to attend to two origins at once.
Does the driver "pauses" the thread and runs the GUI-update? Does it "glFinish" the thread and then attends to GUI update?
In any case that target of avoiding blocking is not achieved. GUI or thread is delayed at least for a small amount of time.

The best option, IMHO, is not to use a secondary thread for gl operation, but just for preparing data.

Thus, the question arises on its own: How is MC-null useful?

Comment: What do you mean NULL? arguments of `MakeCurrent` are platform-dependant values , with some special ones, like `EGL_NO_CONTEXT` for last one (context). Each version of function have own document on what these values should \can be, zero might be a legal  fallback value or something. Using `NULL` instead of `0` everywhere, a thing some C programmers like to do, is somewhat ill-conceived, imho.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I already know that each platform has its own way for the parameters. And so using NULL-or-None-or-0-or-whatever for special, platform-dependant, parameter makes the context to be detached. I tried to be short with "MC-null" name, read it as "*with proper parameters to release the context.*"

Comment: Ah, in that case is main purpose is likely that context can be used only by single thread on some platforms, also window nanagers may require release to end a "paint event"